# gnome-tweaks broken UI

Tags: 19.10, gnome-tweak-tool, gnome-tweaks

I just upgraded from 18.04 to 19.04 to 19.10 and for a day it was seemingly fine. I removed wayland and using x11 now but today, for some reason, gnome-tweaks just bugged out.

[image]

Tweaks opens up like this now. If I toggle a switch, the top bar navigation appears and then I can back out to the main menu:

[image]

And I just discovered that if I leave animations off, the whole UI bugs out. Flickering from one state or another.

I tried removing it with `sudo apt purge gnome-tweaks` and reinstalling but the problem persists.

Can someone shed some light on this please.

Comment: This could be due to the GTK theme you're using. See if changing the theme using dconf-editor (/org/gnome/desktop/interface/gtk-theme) to say Yaru solves this.

Comment: @Logix same issue. I just cannot seem to get a handle on this and I don't know which logs to look at to see what's failing.

Comment: Was everything upgraded properly? See if maybe you need to run "sudo apt install -f", then use"sudo apt full-upgrade" to fully upgrade the system. Then check the Tweaks version and see that you're actually using the version in Ubuntu 19.10 using this command: "apt policy gnome-tweaks", it should say version 3.34. Also... you do use GNOME Shell and not some other desktop environment, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by some weird issue during the upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10.

When the upgrade ended there were no errors and `lsb_release -a` showed `19.10` but for some reason after running `apt update` it showed `19.04`.

I ran the upgrade again and everything was fixed.