# gnome tweaks all greyed out and not appearing in top bar

Tags: 19.10

similar to this

[gnome-tweaks broken UI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204882/gnome-tweaks-broken-ui)

but all my tweaks are greyed out and do not show in the top bar.

I am already using the Yaru theme

all I had done was change autologin to require password.. there are no gears showing to change from Unity to Gnome when logging in, OR the latest update . In any case I am using unity according to

ubuntu 19.10

uname -r kernel is 5.3.5-050305-generic

printf 'Desktop: %s\nSession: %s\n' "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "$GDMSESSION"    Desktop is ubuntu:gnome session is ubuntu.

I have purged and reinstalled gnome-tweaks, and done sudo apt full-upgrade and autoremove.

and rebooted several times.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Tweaks` app, just slide the slide switch that's showing in the top of the Tweaks window, to the right.

**Note**: run the 5.3.5-050305-generic kernel at your own risk.
[image]

Comment: much thanko, I didnt see that one, must have switched by mistake. I will be going onto 19.20 in a couple of months.

Comment: by the way, even though all the tweaks I have to show in the top bar are showing, and they are not greyed out in the tweak extensions page, they are all set in an off position. i have not rebooted though since success with this.

Comment: That is so difficult to see, thank you. No idea how it got disabled